# How to trigger an ajax request after page load in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i am writing a wordpress plugin.
In order to decrease page load time i decided to go with AJAX.So what i mean is when the page loads an ajax must be triggered and the content must be loaded by a request.
My question is that i am not writing a theme,so how can i do this with a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) to load your js into the page and do the ajax request from that js file. Here we are using [wp_head](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head) hook to place it into the `<head>` section of your theme.

```
add_action('wp_head', load_my_scripts);
function load_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-js-file',
        plugins_url('/js/my-js-file.js', __FILE__),
        array('jquery')
    );
}
```

Also if you are developing a custom theme then be sure to have `<?php wp_head(); ?>` before closing you `</head>` tag in your header.php

PS: I'm assuming you are using jQuery for you ajax requests so I included that library in the code as prerequisite, so Wordpress will include that library before your js file.

Comment: Okay,thanks for this.Can i ask you a few questions?
For example,what does __FILE__ do,is it a default parameter or should i set something?
Another question is third parameter array('jquery') what is this mean?

Comment: third parameter is Array of handles of any script that this script depends on (scripts that must be loaded before this script). false if there are no dependencies.

Comment: `__FILE__` is a php magic constant that always returns an absolute path of current php file. [Read More on __FILE__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). You don't need to change it to anything if you are placing this code into one of files in the root of your plugin e.g. your index.php